# Mocha, deep learning tool

Tags: debugging

I am new to deep learning, and have found a tool named "Mocha". This is the tool written in Julia. But I have confronted a bug while I was loading files. The program failed to read files, and I had no idea. The part of code is as follows:

```
using HDF5

datasets = ["train" => ["train-labels.idx1-ubyte","train-images.idx3-ubyte"],
            "test" => ["t10k-labels.idx1-ubyte","t10k-images.idx3-ubyte"]]
```

The compiler reported that HDF5 is not installed properly. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Error is pretty clear, you need to install HDF5. On a mac (assuming you have homebrew) it would be `brew install hdf5.rb`

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I am on a windows, I have tried the command: Pkg.build("HDF5"), and the building time seemed quite long. How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: https://github.com/JuliaIO/HDF5.jl

You can install HDF5 package for Julia by following instructions on the page.

And I wonder why you chose Julia based framework for Deep learning?